# Examples & Applications of Quadratic Phase Coupling

Tags: signal-analysis, frequency-spectrum, phase

Quadratic phase coupling is defined as follows:

> Consider the signal  $$ x(t) = A_{1} \cos(\omega_{1}t+ \phi_{1}) +
> > A_{2}\cos(\omega_{2}t +  \phi_{2}) $$ which is passed through the
> quadratic nonlinear system $$ h(t) = ax^{2}(t) $$ where $a$ is
> non-zero constant. On the output of the system, the signal $x(t)$ will
> include harmonic components: $(2\omega_{1}, 2\phi_{1})$,
> $(2\omega_{2}, 2\phi_{2})$,  $(\omega_{1} + \omega_{2}, \phi_{1} +
> > \phi_{2})$,  $(\omega_{1} - \omega_{2}, \phi_{1} - \phi_{2})$. Such
> phenomenon, which produces a formation of these phase relations, is
> called quadratic phase coupling.

My question is if there are real-life examples and/or applications of quadratic phase coupling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is called out in your quoted section, *any* system that contains a quadratic non-linearity will exhibit a quadratic phase coupling phenomenon to some extent. If it is large enough to be measured is another question. In modeling the dynamics of beam properties (displacement, shear/bending stress, etc.), quadratic and higher-order nonlinear terms are commonly used. For small displacements, these terms are usually considered negligible (common assumptions made in Euler-Bernoulli beam theory).

Keep in mind that systems involving any kind of rotation or periodicity are described by trigonometric terms which are rich with non-linearities and can contain quadratic terms, as can be seen by the Taylor-Series of cosine:
$$\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}+...$$

When measuring the vibrations of rotating machinery, impacts on gears (e.g. from missing gear teeth) cause a periodic impulse which can be modeled as being generated by a non-linear system. From this, studies have been made on the [detection of faults in rotating machines using bicoherence](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1351400), a common measure of quadratic phase coupling, to identify the presence of non-linearities that have been correlated to certain types of damage.

Answer (score 0):

Just about any real-life communications system suffers from [passive intermodulation (PIM).](https://www.anritsu.com/en-us/test-measurement/technologies/pim)  One part of PIM distortions is quadratic (though there are other orders possibly involved too).

[There're many patents involved in systems to reduce PIM.](https://patents.google.com/?q=passive%20intermodulation&oq=passive%20intermodulation)